# Wordpress. Дополнительные CSS стили, display:none

Tags: css, wordpress

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скрыть или убрать "опцию" Other countries
в дополнительных стилях.

[image: Описание]

Answer (score 1):

.wcpbc-country-switcher option[value=AU] {display: none;}